# Rewrite Image Url with parameters using htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cdn

The CDN image URL is

```
https://cdn{sid}.example.com/{f1}/image_{id}.{ext}
```

This is how I will call the image file

```
<img src="image.php?cdn=42&f1=folder&id=1234&ext=jpg" alt="Hello" />
```

The .htaccess code I found so far

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^image.php https://cdn42.example.com/folder/image_1234.jpg
```

How to populate the params (sid, f1, id etc) to htaccess? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm not the downvoter (and don't see any downvotes), but I would suspect it's because you don't make it clear whether the rewrite is being run on the CDN or redirecting from your server to the CDN and you don't indicate what results you're currently getting ... is it not working at all, giving incorrect results, or have you even tried it? Also, this is a very common question if you search here for "query_string". I've supplied an answer based on the assumption you're going from your server to the CDN, but it would be helpful if you supplied more details in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect from `image.php?cdn=42&f1=folder&id=1234&ext=jpg` to `https://cdn{sid}.example.com/{f1}/image_{id}.{ext}`, the following rule should work. This is assuming that you are trying to redirect from your server to the CDN, not trying to rewrite on the CDN itself:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cdn=([^&]*)&f1=([^&]*)&id=([^&]*)&ext=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^image.php$ https://cdn%1.example.com/%2/image_%3.%4
```